# Bash Script that backs up MySQL Database

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a script and I keep getting the following errors.  access denied for user 'zul'@'localhost (using password:yes) when trying to connect

proj: 43: [d: not found

proj: 43: [d: not found

It's not reading the input d nor is it connecting to MySQL. Any Ideas?

Here is my Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tstamp=$(date +$s) 

#Dump or Update
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo -n "What do you want to do? [D]ump or [U]pdate: "
  read parm
else
  parm=$1
fi

#Database Name
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
  echo -n "What database are you using?"
  read dbname
else
  dbname=$2
fi

#Database User
if [ -z "$3" ]; then
  echo -n "What database user are you using?"
  read dbuser
else
  dbuser=$3
fi

#Database Password
if [ -z "$4" ]; then
     echo -n "What password are you using?"
     read dbpass
else
     dbpass=$4
fi


#Checks if the directory exists
if test ! -d "/home/zul/sql/backup"; then
  mkdir /home/zul/sql
  mkdir /home/zul/sql/backup
fi

mysqldump $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > /home/zul/sql/backup/$tstamp.$dbname.sql

if [$parm = d ]; then
  mysqldump $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > /home/zul/sql/backup/$dbname.sql
elif [$parm = u ]; then
  mysqldump $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname < /home/zul/sql/backup/$dbname.sql
else
  echo " d or u option only! (lower case)"
fi
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially just constructing a command line to call mysqldump? I'd question the usefulness of such a script. It sounds, atleast to me, like one more thing to maintain with not much benefit.

Comment: Did you try to run with `bash -vx` your script? This helps a lot and would let you found your bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a space missing in your if-else test:
Should be `[ test ]` and not `[test ]`

```
if [ $parm = d ]; then
  mysqldump $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > /home/zul/sql/backup/$dbname.sql
elif [ $parm = u ]; then
  mysqldump $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname < /home/zul/sql/backup/$dbname.sql
else
```

Comment: and the reason for this is that it is parsed as `[test` being a command (`[d: not found` - meaning, there is no command called `[d`)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any Ideas why I get the access denied for user 'zul'@'localhost? I enter the correct password but it still gives me that error.

Comment: zul is not allowed to connect from localhost.

Comment: @KD: there is not code that sets `$dbpass` in the script you posted

Comment: @KD: that doesn't look like a problem with your script.

Answer (score 1):

You must separate '[' from its arguments with whitespace:

```
if [ $parm = d ]; then
    mysqldump $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > /home/zul/sql/backup/$dbname.sql
elif [ $parm = u ]; then
```